# Rust generate .so file for linux from Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, rust, cross-platform

i created a cross-platform lib that i would use to a .NET6 application using P/Invoke.

I've generated correctly the file dll, now i would generate .so for linux from VSCode, then i installed the target with rustup

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

And build without error with

```
cargo build  --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

But in debug folder can't find the .so file just a .d and rlib file
Is there any other step i need to generate .so?

In cargo.toml i added

```
[lib]
name="gx_hid"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

Thanks

Content of build folder [image]

Comment: To be clear, what exactly are the contents of your `target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug` after running the build?

Comment: Added in the post, what i understood is that the .so will start with 'lib' but i can't find or generate

Comment: Is the directory listing you shared `target/debug` or `target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug`?

Comment: It's target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug, in target/debug i have .dll

Comment: It's interesting that `.cargo-lock` is present, which suggests a `cargo` invocation hasn't finished using that output directory (perhaps it terminated uncleanly?).

Comment: cargo-lock is 0 bytes probably empty

Answer (score 0):

Solved using https://github.com/cross-rs/cross

Install Docker on windows
Install Cross with command

```
cargo install cross --git https://github.com/cross-rs/cross
```

And build with target you want

```
cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

It automatically download and install docker image and build, and correctly generate .so file